# Error Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have an error with my mvc3 application.

In my application I have a reference to a vb6 DLL which is a dll of another program.

When I debug my application with VisualStudio server developpement all is ok but I tried to deploy it in IIS7.5

I changed in the properties of my application the server and I chose local IIS webServer. (I didn't change the properties of IIS since the installation).

And when I try to debug my application I have an error when instanciating my dll :

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID .... Class not registered

This dll was registered with regsvr32.

The same application was deploy on a server with windows server 2003 and IIS6 and it works correctly.

If anybody have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If the COM component is 32bit you will have to enable 32 bit applications in IIS:

[image]

Comment: This did it for me. +1 Darin.  I was going mad too because the OCX was already registered.